# iOS App Ready for sale status but not appearing in the store

Tags: ios, app-store

My iOS app shows status "Ready for sale" in my iTunes connect account. The status changed 3 hours back. I am able to view the app when i click in the link provided in my iTunes connect account. My app is not available when i search it in the store. How much time does it take for the app to come up on the store.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

First of all, Please search and review as there are numbers of questions related to this topic or we can say duplicate.

Yes, after your app gets Status `Ready for Sale` it might take some time for after that the app will be visible as search result. Totally depends on `Apple` as The delay is due to propagating your application's status across their all `iTunes app stores` servers. it will take maximun a day.

This is what i learnt from somewhere want to share as `Apple` cache the data that will shows in the search result on `iTunes App store`. So I think this will take couple of hours for their caches to be updated.

Answer (score 16):

Usually it takes under 3 hours but it's totally up to Apple. Sometimes it takes a day...