# App not appearing on App store search

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, app-store-connect

I have released the first version of my app a couple of days ago & it was available on app store search. I have rolled an update with some bug fixes a day later & the updated version got the status "ready to sale" and was available in app store updates within 6 hours.

But the strange thing i have observed is that, the app was only available from the standard link and was not appearing on app store search.

People were able to download the app using the link but it wasn't showing up on search (even after using the exact name). Any help would be highly valued and appreciated !

PS : when i rolled an update, i changed the keywords and category of the app to more relevant ones.

Comment: People had same issue here:  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24545091/ios-app-ready-for-sale-status-but-not-appearing-in-the-store)

Did you contact them? They might be faster resolving your problem...

Comment: I've tried , but of no use

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There could be many reasons for not showing up into the search results. Here are few explained :

- May be the ASO changes you have done are not reflected yet so it will not appear in to search. In that case you should wait for 24-48 hours to let things go & settle
- Another major & important reason is if App name you are using is very common or already is too much use in other similar apps which already are in the market before your release than also it will put your app far back into the search results that even don't show in limited search results
- ASO factor will also effect your app to not appear into the search results. May be you should use more strong keywords which can help your app to compete with other similar apps. You can try & use ASO tools for that.
- Last but not the least some times apple has some inner maintenance works which they do silently also affects sometimes to the search results

So from above points the solution is :

- Wait for the few hours at least 48 hours to let crawl your ASO keywords & lets get effect in to search result improvements
- If it not works since 48 hours you should appeal to apple review team for the same.

Hope it will work to everyone.